# YouCompleteMe(YCM) doesnt suggest any formats (C11)

Tags: c, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I'm trying to setup YCM to utilize autocompletion in C.
I followed up the instruction described in the manaul.(:help YouCompleteMe)
However it doen't show any autocompletion list for me.
Part of flags in my ycm_extra_conf.py and debug info are like below. 
(ps, I also post my current status when I open C file and type pri (it should suggests printf or etc...)

Thanks :)

[image: MY CURRENT STATUS]

[image: YCM DEBUG INFO]

```
  '-std=c11',
  '-x',
  'c'
  '-isystem',
  '../BoostParts',
  '-isystem',
  '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers',
  '-isystem',
  '../llvm/include',
  '-isystem',
  '../llvm/tools/clang/include',
  '-I',
  '.',
  '-I',
  './ClangCompleter',
  '-isystem',
  './tests/gmock/gtest',
  '-isystem',
  './tests/gmock/gtest/include',
  '-isystem',
  './tests/gmock',
  '-isystem',
  './tests/gmock/include',
  #C default header
  '-isystem',
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu',
  '-isystem',
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include',
  '-isystem',
  '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed',
  '-isystem',
  '/usr/local/include',
  '-isystem',
  '/usr/include',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the very beginning:

```
'-std=c11',
'-x',
'c'
'-isystem',
```

Last two items become `c-isystem` (see `:YcmDebug` output). It may confuse compiler. I guess you meant `-c` instead. Nevertheless such flag is redundant for `YouCompleteMe` and may be omitted safely.

P.S. C++ headers confuse C compiler too, so you need to ensure that provided headers are consistent with current source file type (is it C or C++).

Comment: OMG.. I missed the comma..! Thank @Sergio :)